# AsyncMock coroutines never actually yield control?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I'm trying to test some asynchronous code I wrote. The structure is:

- A worker object is responsible for receiving a task and asynchronously executing it, often `await`ing on some asynchronous IO call
- Sitting above each worker object is a loop that reads from a shared queue, passing tasks down to the worker as each task becomes available. Note that this queue is persistent, and in reality I'm using a blocking persistent queue library.
- At the very top is an `asyncio.gather` call, waiting on each of the inner loops.
  I've constructed a toy example:

```py
import asyncio


async def loop_inner(worker, worker_num, tasks):
    while tasks:
        task = tasks.pop()
        print('Worker number {} handled task number {}'.format(
            worker_num, await worker.do_work(task)))


async def loop(workers, tasks):
    tasks = [loop_inner(worker, worker_num, tasks) for
                     worker_num, worker in enumerate(workers)]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

When run on a real workload, the structure works great. High throughput, good use of parallelism, etc.

The problem is when I want to test it. I'd like to write tests that mimic the distribute of tasks across the various workers. However, I want to test just the distribution logic, while mocking out the worker code itself. My natural impulse is to replace real workers with `AsyncMock` objects. Problem is, when I run this test case, all the work is being handled by a single worker:

```py
from unittest import IsolatedAsyncioTestCase, main
from unittest.mock import ANY, AsyncMock, patch

class TestCase(IsolatedAsyncioTestCase):
    async def test_yielding(self):
        tasks = list(range(10))
        workers = [AsyncMock() for i in range(2)]
        for worker in workers:
            worker.do_work.side_effect = lambda task: task

        await loop(workers, tasks)

main()
```

My output is as follows:

```
Worker number 0 handled task number 9
Worker number 0 handled task number 8
Worker number 0 handled task number 7
Worker number 0 handled task number 6
Worker number 0 handled task number 5
Worker number 0 handled task number 4
Worker number 0 handled task number 3
Worker number 0 handled task number 2
Worker number 0 handled task number 1
Worker number 0 handled task number 0
```

What gives? Why is just one worker handling all the work? Is the event loop not passing control off to the other worker? Is the `AsyncMock` coroutine not really yielding control? What can I do to more realistically test this?

Comment: If the `lambda` voluntarily yields control, perhaps through `sleep(1e-3)`, does that improve the evenness of   scheduling for you? (Feel free to turn the `lambda` into a proper `def`!)

Comment: Ha! It looks like this did it. I replaced the `side_effect` lambda with an async function that just sleeps for one millisecond and it works. Feel free to upgrade your comment to a result, although I'm going to wait to accept it because I still don't quite understand why it behaves in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is just one worker handling all the work?

Scheduler will never interrupt upon quantum expiration, as
we are using cooperative threads here.
So *cooperate*.

Computing `list(range(10))` never yields control.

Voluntarily yielding control with a brief `sleep` in the `lambda`,
or structuring it as an async function,
gives the scheduler an opportunity to keep more than one plate
[spinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plate_spinning) simultaneously.